# Unix - Remove all lowercase characters from a string

Tags: unix

I have sequences of the genetic code like this: `ACTGgcttaTGCA` and I'm trying to figure out the Unix commands to remove lowercase characters only, so that the string then appears as `ACTGTGCA` *(gctta removed)*.

Can anyone offer any advice as to the appropriate means to do this? The files are too large to open in a text editor therefore I can't simply do 'find and replace'.

Comment: Which Unix are you talking about? "Unix" is a family name that covers lots of different implementations; if you tell us which one you are interested in, we can give you answers tailored to your situation. Also, this may receive more attention if migrated to [unix.se] instead; if you want your question migrated, "flag" it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/[a-z]//g' yourfile >> newfile
```

If you want to edit the file in-place:

```
sed -i 's/[a-z]//g' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can just find and replace, you just need to do it on the stream rather than then loading the whole file. Usually you'd use the tool `sed` for this. This could look like the following:

```
sed -r 's/[a-z]*//g' input.txt
```

This would match any sequence of lowercase characters and replace them with nothing.